# Reading public files from internal storage into the app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, readfile

I want the user to be able to put certain files (for example config.txt and background.jpg) into a specific folder on his tablet, which are then read and used by the app (without any direct user input in the app itself).

For now i have some testfiles in the assets-folder, but i have a hard time converting this to what i actually need.

So where do i put the files and how can i read them?

I may not need the exact code, a hint into the right direction could be enough.

Thank you.

Comment: You put files in assets and use them at run time. Ok. Normal. But what does that have to do with the user placing files on storage and your app reading them?

Comment: I dont want to have the files in the assets, because i want the user to have access to those files (write, edit, delete etc.), which is not possible if they are in assets (correct?).

Comment: Indeed. But normally you would copy those files from assets to storage if the user had to edit them. And i wonder where the user would get those files from if your app did not bring them in assets. I'm puzzled what you want.

Comment: I dont want to give the user any files, he needs to put some files somewhere, which are then interpreted by the app. So for example, he can put a background.jpg in the specified folder, which is then used by the app as a background picture in a specific activity. Also he can put .txt-files, which are used to fill certain Textviews.

Comment: How does a user put a file in a folder? This is already a user action! Why dont you just let the user select a file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Comment: Please see my edit, in the above statement. I misclicked.

Also thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: Not via the app, just regular filesystemstuff.

Comment: Could you be more specific? And if a user can place a file in a folder you still need further user inter action as with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: Ok maybe i have to explain a little more to make it clear.

There will actually be two users. One user (lets call him admin) can edit the contents that the app is showing via certain files. This is done before the app is started or anything. Then he starts the app (which is kind of a game) an then gives it to the second user (lets call him player). So the player should not be able to interact with the stuff thats going on behind the scenes, he just sees what the admin put in the files.

I hope that makes sense.